# insert data in another table then update data in current table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have two tables with the same fields : `vessel_details` and `vessel_history`. There is a form provided to the user for the renewal of the vessel license. Upon page load, all the data of the vessel will be displayed(textbox) through the form. These data are retrieved from the `vessel_details` table. Once the user edited the details, and clicked the update button, the original details(before the editing) from the `vessel_details` should be transferred in the `vessel_history` table before the updating of the current filled-out/edited details in the `vessel_details`.

upon clicking the update button, how can i insert the original details from the table `vessel_details` to the other table (`vessel_history`),and eventually update the `vessel_details` table with the new (edited) details?

Comment: If you're using Sql Server Standard or Express Editions, consider purchasing Sql Server Enterprise Edition. This allows you to use a service called [Change Data Capture](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx), which make this entire feature in your app unnecessary. While Enterprise Edition is expensive, when you have a nice line-up with a feature like this, it's often much cheaper and more effective than the equivalent programmer time building and maintaining a feature like this into your app.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what technique you are using to get you data, what you can do is clone original record container which might be a DTO or dataset or something else. Again you have to decide whether is deep clone or shadow clone and on update clone goes to history table and original updates values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a trigger in the database to do this. Then no matter what technology you use at the front end it will always work.